# How to use Python thread with Flask in Apache

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app to Apache webserver.

In my main file, before running the Flask app, I start a daemon thread that runs in background:

```
# ... here there are all the imports and the Flaks routes

def main():
  x = threading.Thread(target=my_thread_function)
  x.daemon = True
  x.start()
  
  # app.run() # I moved this line below

  x.join() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
  app.run()
```

This is my `wsgi`  file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\myapp\\')
from myapp import app as application
```

If I run Apache server, Flask works fine and I can see the web app interface when I connect to the IP address. However, the background thread doesn't work, because I don't see its "effect" in the app.

If I run the same code with the Flask development server, the background thread works fine.

How can it work with Apache?

Answer (score 0):

remove the `join()` because it will block the `app.run()`

```
# ... here there are all the imports and the Flaks routes

def main():
  x = threading.Thread(target=my_thread_function)
  x.daemon = True
  x.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
  app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work!